# A JS Combination Lock

Tags: javascript

I need a function that does the following...

- takes four arguments that are all numbers
- returns "correct" if the numbers are a valid combo
- returns "incorrect" if the numbers are invalid
- a combo is valid if

  - the first number is a 3, 5, or 7
  - the second number is 2
  - the third number is between 5 and 100, 5 and 100 are both valid
  - the fourth number is less than 9 **or** greater than 20, 9 and 20 are both invalid

I've come up with this

```
var lock = function(one, two, three, four) {
  if((one === 3 || one === 5 || one === 7) && (two === 2) && ((5 <= three) && (three <= 100)) && ((four < 9) || (four > 20))) {
    return "correct";
  }
  else {
    return "incorrect";
  }
};
```

But unfortunately `lock(3, 2, 5, 4);`  returns "incorrect", which as far as I tell it shouldn't. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

#### Here's a [pen](http://codepen.io/codeandcam/pen/cqyKm) to play with regarding the topic.

Comment: "the fourth number is less than 9 and greater than 20, 9 and 20 are both invalid" : How can a number be less than 9 but greater than 20 ? Or do you mean  "less than 9 **or** greater than 20" ?

Comment: My error.. Thanks for pointing that out! Solved it.

Answer (score 6):

`(four < 9) && (four > 20)` is always false.